# How to include element symbol in graphviz?

Tags: math, symbols, graphviz

I want to include the element symbol (∈, [Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics)#Notation_and_terminology)) into a Graphviz graph.

`isElementOf [label=<&#8712;>]`

How is this done correctly? Code above gives a different symbol (square with four zeroes).

Example of wrong end result:

[image: Link 1]

Example of correct end result:

[image: Link 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this `isElementOf [label=<&#8712;>]`

[image]

```
digraph G {

  subgraph cluster_0 {
    style=filled;
    color=lightgrey;
    node [style=filled,color=white];
    a0 -> a1 -> a2 -> a3;
    label = "process #1";
  }

  subgraph cluster_1 {
    node [style=filled];
    b0 -> b1 -> b2 -> b3;
    label = "process #2";
    color=blue
  }
  start -> a0;
  start -> b0;
  a1 -> b3;
  b2 -> a3;
  a3 -> a0;
  a3 -> end;
  b3 -> end;

  start [shape=Mdiamond];
  end [label=<&#8712;>];
}
```

Comment: While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this 
code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: No, this doesn't work - results in an error actually. Added in question the requested end result.

Comment: Please add the code as code in this question not as an image. What is the `sign` after the A in line 26

Comment: Thanks! Turns out it looks like a PDF issue, because there the four zeroes square symbol appears, whereas the SVG output shows the correct symbol.